# From curl to jQuery AJAX post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, curl

Hi i want to convert this cmd curl to JQuery Ajax Post :

```
curl -k -X POST https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/domains/MyDomain/applications 
--user "user@myemail.com:password" 
--data "name=myapp&cartridge=php-5.3&scale=true"
```

thats what i do :

```
 jQuery.ajax({
     url: 'https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/domains/MyDomain/applications ',
     username: 'user@myemail.com',
     password: 'password',
     type: 'POST',
     dataType: 'json',
     contentType: 'application/json',
     processData: false,
     data: 'name=myapp&cartridge=php-5.3&scale=true"',
     success: function (data) {
         alert(JSON.stringify(data));
     },
     error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
     }
 });
```

and i get this error after submitting in my alerte :

```
(<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
 <title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
 <h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/domains/MyDomain/applications      was not found on this server.</p>
  <hr>
  <address>Apache/2.4.6 (Fedora) Server at drupal-pcsol.openshift.local Port 80</address>
 </body></html>
)
```

Any ideas please ?

Comment: in `error: function(xhr, status, error) {` can you alert the value of `xhr.responseText`?

Comment: it's null, nothing in the `xhr.responseText`

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem. `eval("()");` will give you syntax error.

Comment: Thanks, removing `eval` removed the `syntaxe error` but i still have the `xhr.responseText` empty, any ideas

Comment: `data: 'name=myapp&cartridge=php-5.3&scale=true"',` is not `contentType: 'application/json',`

Comment: What does the Net tab of your developer tools show? Is the request formatted as you expect? Is the response formatted as you expect? What does the Console tab show? Are there any JavaScript errors?

Comment: Thanks for all your responce, i have edit my question if you have any ideas

Answer (score -1):

AFAICS, this is a cross domain request, which is not allowed in Ajax.

Learn more: [Same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)